# Game stops when I back to screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx, crash

I have a project that has 3 screens: a home screen, the main game screen and the game over screen.  The game over screen has buttons to go to the home screen or play again.  When I start the game, it works normally but when I die in the game and want to play again I can't because the game stops by pushing the button "play again" to go to my main game.  What can it be?

Comment: Can you check if there are error logs and post it here to make the question clearer?